# How can I add translate to <SimpeForm /> validation in React Admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I can't translate the validation message in [React Admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/) . The validation return only the validated string (example.: app.errors.startIsRequired, not the translated string (example: Start is required).

Example:

Form.js

```
 <SimpleForm
        toolbar={<LoggingChangeToolbar label={submitButtonText} />}
        validate={ValidateLoggingChangeForm}
        className={"logging-form"}
        save={handleSubmit}
        redirect={false}
      >

....

</Simpleform>
```

Validation.js

```
export const ValidateManualLogForm = (values) => {
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.start) {
    errors.start = 'app.errors.startIsRequired';
  }

  if (!values.end) {
    errors.end = 'app.errors.endIsRequired';
  } else if (values.start > values.end) {
    errors.end = 'app.errors.endMustBeGreaterThanStart';
  }

  if (!values.project) {
    errors.project = 'app.errors.projectIsRequired';
  }

  if (!values.description) {
    errors.description = 'app.errors.descriptionIsRequired';
  }

  return errors;
};
```

Comment: Could you provide your setup for the i18nProvider? and it's messages? I assume it's not being translated because it's not properly configured, or it was an older version of the lib that had the issue that was already fixed (since it's a post from 2 years ago)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue described in the post has been already fixed by the dependency developer.